# How to Read Audio file Using cordova file system

Tags: ionic-framework, cordova-plugins

**Here is the Method Defined to read Audio File Using Cordova File System

and Ionic File System:**

```
function readFile() {
     var type = window.TEMPORARY;
     var size = 5*1024*1024;
     window.requestFileSystem(type, size, successCallback, errorCallback)

     function successCallback(fs) {
        fs.root.getFile('remo.mp3', {}, function(fileEntry) {

           fileEntry.file(function(file) {
              var reader = new FileReader();
              console.log(file);
              reader.onloadend = function(e) {
                 console.log(this.result);
              };
              reader.readAsText(file);
           }, errorCallback);
        }, errorCallback);
     }

     function errorCallback(error) {
        alert("ERROR: " + error.code);
     }
   }
```

Output Of The Code is Having size of zero and with some other keys of like name, start etc:

```
File {  
   name : "remos.mp3"
   size : 0,
   start: 0
   type : "audio/mpeg"
}
```

Comment: I found the solution by myself  `try to use : window.resolveLocalFileSystemURL(cordova.file.externalRootDirectory + fileName, gotFile, fail);`  and get output with some SIZE

Answer (score 2):

//Yes, I found the solution for it, You need to just upload body of audio file as BLOB object like

```
fileEntry.file(function(file) {

                var reader = new FileReader();
                console.log(file);



                reader.onloadend = function(e) {


                    blob = new Blob([new Uint8Array(this.result)], { type: file.type });

                    objectBlob = {file:file,blob:blob};

                    $scope.uploadS3(objectBlob, function(data) {

                        console.log(data);

                        $rootScope.audioObject = 
                        {
                            cloudLocation:data.Location,
                            uploadDateTime:getCurrentTime(),
                            objId:$scope.randomString(6)
                        };

                        console.log($rootScope.audioObject)

                    });
                };

                reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);                         

            });
```